# How to remove Text from image (.jpg/png) in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

sorry for bad English,

I want to implement the koreakoe song.
and i have 1 video for that.
so i can take each frame from **MediaMetadataRetriever** class in android.
in Bitmap format. and each bitmap contain one image and some text.

So my question is how to get this text on image and after **remove this text from image or highlight each word on current image.**

i have no such code that
please give me suggestion.

Please see the below image for example..

[image]

**Then after**

[image]

**OR**

[image]

if you some clarification please ask me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you see some text in an image, that's not a separate object you can manipulate (i.e.: removing or highlighting a word).

Because that text is not a string. It's part of the bitmap itself.
It's a bunch of colored pixels over a bunch of colored pixels.

Thereafter, you can't easily remove it if not using a graphic editor or some AI techniques.

**[EDIT]**

A tricky solution would be to **COVER** the text with something else.
I.e.: a textView with an opaque background. There you will put YOUR text.
This can be easily achieved, by using a RelativeLayout.

I said it's TRICKY. Probably it's not the best visual solution, but it may help you solve the urgency.

**[EDIT 2]**

Another tricky solution would be to **CUT** the text potion of the image.
I.e.: you CROP the image at a specified amount of pixels.

Again, I said this is TRICKY, too. Probably it's not the easiest way, but it may result in a better visual rendering, allowing you to use a TRANSPARENT background for your text.

Comment: Tricky? OK, COVER the text with something. I.e.: a textView with an opaque background. There you will put YOUR text.

Comment: But i have take image from Video so string any place may be.so how achieve your solution.
your 2nd tricky solution how to cut specific (text)area.

Comment: So, the text is not at a fixed position? In this case, you can't. OR you'r going to become mad by editing each frame manually and then reassemble the video.

Comment: :- yes text is not in fix position.

Comment: So, you are screwed, since you have no way to know WHERE the text will appear in time... :( I hoped you had a single image and just put a text over it. Or a series of images with the text at a fixed location.

Comment: One image contain number of sentence in my case.

Comment: You posted 3 pictures. The 1st is with text at a certain (x, y). Another one is empty (which you want). The 3rd is the same as the 1st, witht he same text positioning (x1=x, y1=y). Only a word changed color. If you want this, take the 2nd image, put a TextView on it and change the text in the TextView as required... Am I entering in a confusional state of mind?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an image without text and then lay the text over the image using a `TextView`. I hope it is then clear how to manipulate the text without changing the image.
As Bob Malooga already stated, there is no easy and flawless way to remove text that is actually part of the bitmap, so you should separate the image from the text.